# PDF or HTML versions of Spatial Query Lab (FOSS4G Academy) lectures by Rick Smith

Tags: open-source-gis, references

I am Spatial Science Teacher at TAFE NSW teaching Spatial Information Systems online.  In 2019 our department started including links to many of the Spatial Query Lab SQL lectures in our resources. We found them to be excellent as they were software-neutral and pitched lots of GIS concepts at just the right level for our students who need theoretical information at a simpler level than many university level texts.  The Labs for these classes are available here: https://github.com/FOSS4GAcademy/GST102FOSS4GLabs but not the lectures.

Does anyone know how to contact Rick Smith (previously at Richard.Smith@tamucc.edu) or anyone who might have a copy of these lectures?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question a short while ago and thought I had better share for those who are interested.
Richard Smith has moved the resources to a site called Skills Commons.
The Lectures are located here:
https://www.skillscommons.org/handle/taaccct/5237# for GST 101 (Introduction to Geospatial Technology)
https://www.skillscommons.org/handle/taaccct/5369 for GST 102 (Spatial analysis)
https://www.skillscommons.org/handle/taaccct/5395 for GST 103 (Data acquisition & management)
https://www.skillscommons.org/handle/taaccct/5440 for GST 104 (Cartographic Design) and
https://www.skillscommons.org/handle/taaccct/5447 for GST 105 (Introduction to Remote Sensing)